# in MySQL, how to use information from one table to update another table

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, cursor

I have two tables: teams, and persons.

table `teams` have three columns, `id`, `name`, `leader`

table `persons` have these columns: `hash`, `team_id`

teams.leader is a MD5 hash that must match persons.hash in order to determine which person is leader of a given team.

I need to run a query on MySQL that does the following:

1) Retrieve all the leaders of a team, and the team id:

```
SELECT `id`,`leader` FROM `teams`;
```

2) Use such information to update `team_id` on table `persons`

This is my current Query:
     SELECT `id` FROM `teams` INNER JOIN `persons` ON `teams`.`leader` = `persons`.`hash`

but I haven't been able to come up with a solution that allows me update column `team_id` with the corresponding leader.
I've been thinking probably using cursors, but not sure about it.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the multiple table `UPDATE` syntax to join the tables:

```
UPDATE teams JOIN persons ON teams.leader = persons.hash
SET persons.team_id = teams.id
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know It was possible to use JOIN along with UPDATE. I'll choose this answer as the best one in 10 minutes or so.